# "Would" usage in this sentence

Tags: grammar, word-usage, future-tense

*The truth is that I loved him and I stood by
him and he sent me to you,*
*like he* **would** *send a stagehand
to pick up his shirts.*


What is the usage of **would** in this sentence?

I think would is only used in conditionals, requests, things you used to do , future from the past view. But I cannot understand why it is used there because it seems like it is **tenseless**.

It is an dialogue from 2007 movie **"The Prestige"**.

Comment: For this to be accepted as a question, you need to include some reason why you are having difficulty understanding how the word 'would' is being used here.  What is there about it that sounds strange to you?  Above all, what have you done to find out an explatantion for yourself?

Comment: ok i am editing.

Comment: It does seem to come under "things you used to do"